# Clustering with disjunct pairs

Tags: clustering, matrix-decomposition

I am looking for an algorithm to cluster elements of which I already know pairs that are *not* in the same cluster.

Take the following matrix. The values in the cells represent a score of closeness (the higher the closer). A negative value indicates that the elements cannot be in the same cluster.

```
-  a  b  c  d  e
a  -  4 -1  2  6
b  -  -  3  5 -1
c  -  -  - -1  4
d  -  -  -  -  7
```

A possible clustering of these elements is as follows.
`{a, d, e}, {b, c}`.

Notice that the pairs `(a, c)`, `(b, e)`, and `(c, d)` are separated in the clustering.

**Are there any algorithms that consider this kind of prior knowledge about the target clusters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are semi-supervised clustering algorithms known as "**constraint clustering**.

There are often two kinds of constraints considered:

- **must-link constraints**: objects that are known to belong to the same cluster
- **cannot-link constraints**: objects that are known to be different clusters